# Laravel migrate not create table in postgresql database

Tags: migration, laravel-5.4

I am a beginner to Laravel. I would like to ask why Laravel migrate not create my table in my database? This is my .env file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:9FLWfylvrtxjXdunJujBDq37Q4QtKcoiPdmeJbgbLSg=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=laravel5
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=1111

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
```

This is my migrate file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateMySongsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('songs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('artist');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('songs');
    }
}
```

Firstly 
1.run php artisan migrate
Migrated: 2017_02_08_130207_create_articles_table

then in postgresql run 
newFootball=# \dt
No relations found.

Please somebody helps me. Thanks you for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i found the solution. Due to changes in the .env file needed to run the following command.

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Then all working perfect. Thank you.